# Functionality of 'Recent places' in Windows 8 (in Classic shell) lost

Tags: windows-8.1

My Recent places stopped populating after an indiscreet deletion. Is there any way that the link between 'Recent' and the Recent places folder can be reconstituted? What is 'Recent' anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Recent  places display the recent activity you have done including the information of access the file,browsing file using file explorer,opening the application.

You have option to enable/disable the recent places by following the steps

1.Go to  the desktop, right click or press and hold on a empty area on the taskbar, click/tap on Properties.

2.Now an pop-up window open,Chose jump list and Please check To Store and display recently opened items in the Start menu and the task bar box to show the item in the recent list.

3.There would be option to show the no of item in the jump list.

If you unchecked the option,recent place wont be shown.

Comment: Great  thanks for this information. Problem solved.

Comment: Great to know that issue is solved.